# Best Practice for Context Processors vs. Template Tags?

Tags: django, django-templates

In which cases is it better to create template tags (and load them into the template), than creating a context processor (which fills the request automatically)?

e.g. I have a dynamic menu that has to be included into all templates, so I'm putting it into my base.html. What is the preferred usage: context processor or custom template tag? And **why**?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Context processors is for putting data (information, content, objects) into the context used to render page.

Template tags are for formatting or processing that content.

A template tag that makes up new data is confusing.  Not impossible or wrong, but very confusing.

Comment: not necessarily in my opinion:

    {% load advertisementtags %}{% get_top_ads as myads %}
    {% for ad in myads %}...{% endfor %}

that's the way with template tags. with a context processor, I could put "myads" into the context as well. That's why I was asking for "best practices" stuff.

Maybe it's just a matter of taste.

Comment: @mawimawi: It's not a matter of taste.  "Advertisement tags" *should* come from a context processor -- they're content.  Technically, *anything* is possible, including really hard-to-understand things.  it's simpler if content comes from context.