# Django: automatically send variable to templates from every view?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-1.4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I pass data to any template from any view in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071572/how-can-i-pass-data-to-any-template-from-any-view-in-django)

I wonder if there's a way to make every view send a variable or include it in the request context to every template automatically? Something like the messages framework?

My problem is that I want a sidebar on every page rendered with information, say the 10 latest profile pages the user has entered. The only other alternative that I can think of is calling `get_recent_users` at the end of every view and send it to the template as variable, but I don't like that solution because I've got a lot of views. The rendering of it can be easily managed by the base template I use for template inheritance.

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention that the data that I want to access is stored in request.session, if that makes it easier.

Comment: That is true. I used the template context solution and it was super easy and worked perfect, but when I got back to mark the answer as accepted it was deleted :(

Comment: Okay ... i restored my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for a [`context processor`](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/).

Answer (score 0):

Write your [Custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags), and use it in any template you want.

Comment: I'm sure that would be a good solution but I did it with the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS instead.

Comment: Its easy to do with TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS, but you can also do the same thing with Template tags. Mostly Template tags used for formatting or processing the content. check this for more details http://stackoverflow.com/a/2791780/534790