# Django, Template tags vs. Context Processors

Tags: django, django-templates

I can't understand different between Template tags and Context Processors in django template.
I already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791696/best-practice-for-context-processors-vs-template-tags). However I can't understand everything.

Template tags is used in easy processing, tailoring the data, etc., while Context Processors is used in getting entirely different data. Is my understanding correct?

I think Context Processors is easier to use because not need to `{% load ~~ %}`.　Is the reason why Context Processors is not used? it's because it need to Heavy processing?

I'm sorry, my English is hard to understand ：(

Waiting for your answer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For context processor the most important thing when you need to make something available globally to all templates.For example you can ask that like  user is_ authenticated?, is_admin? and get_or_create group.It provide us global actions

Comment: thank you for the simpler explanation!! I can understand now.

Answer (score 1):

Let me share my way of using the template tag and context processor.

## context_processors.py

```
from billing.models import customerType

def get_menu(request):
    customerTypes = customerType.objects.filter(active=True)
    item = []
    for customerType in customerTypes:
        item = {
            'name': customerType.name,
            'slug': customerType.slug
        }
        cp_customerType_list.append(item)
    return {'cp_customerType_list': cp_customerType_list}
```

## settings.py

```
...
"context_processors": [
    ...
    "billing.context_processors.get_menu",
    ...
],
...
```

## customer_type_template_tag.py

```
from django import template
from django.http import request
from billing.context_processors import get_menu

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('billing/tags/customer_types.html')
def get_customer_types_list():
    return get_menu(request)
```

## customer_types.html

```
<ul class="slide-menu">
    {% for cp_customerType in cp_customerType_list %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'billing_customer_list' customerType.slug=cp_customerType.slug %}">
            {{cp_customerType.name}}
        </a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

## base.html

```
<!doctype html>
...
<!-- at the top of the base.html page -->
{% load customer_type_template_tags %}
...
<!-- at the point of loading the customer types menu -->
{% get_customer_types_list %}
...
```

Comment: The get_customer_types_list which is self contained with data and style can now be dropped on any page and will appear the same way.

Answer (score 0):

They are two different things. context is data that you pass from a view to a template like user, form, some_object and ...

Django Template Tags are simple Python functions that accept one or more value, an optional argument, process those values and return a value to be displayed on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a template tag as a mini page with UI build and ready to be used in any page. It will appear the same way without any further modification. If you were to use context processor to provide data in every page, you'd have to write the html code to make the data appear the way you want. If that data needs to appear in many pages, you'd have to repeat the html code in each page.

Comment: give an example that would be helpfull